# Powershell script to check TPM Manufacturer Version with (IF ELSE)

Tags: powershell, tpm

I'm trying to downgrade TPM on several HP laptops. I'm attempting to create a powershell script that will grab the TPM Manufacturer Version number, and check that number against a list of possible numbers. Once it matches one of those number execute the program to downgrade the TPM version.

I started with throwing the output into a variable, and attempting to check the variable against a static number to start the correct program. The variable is stored, but when I try to check it against "7.61" it doesn't seem to be actually checking the result. The result of 7.61 is not returning "Success"

I realize powershell is different, and my IF ELSE statements are probably just outdated. Any help would be very appreciated!

Assume TPM ManufacturerVersion is 7.61

```
    $variable = get-WmiObject -Namespace root\cimv2\security\microsofttpm -Class Win32_Tpm | Select-Object ManufacturerVersion | Out-String

    if($variable -eq "8"){
    Write-Host "success"
    }else{
    Write-Host "Fail"
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vg7V7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing strings, rather than 'versions'.  If you are only checking for simple equality, then using a direct string comparison will do:

```
PS C:\> "10.5" -eq "10.5"
True
```

However, if you want to determine, say, if one version is greater than another, strings won't work.  For example:

```
PS C:\> "100.5" -gt "55.3"
False
```

In that case, you should cast the version strings to actual [Version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version(v=vs.110).aspx) types, then the comparison will work properly.  For example:

```
$tmp = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\cimv2\security\microsofttpm" -Class Win32_TPM

if ([Version]$tmp.ManufacturerVersion -eq [Version]"8.0")
{
    "Success"
}
else
{
    "Fail"
}
```

Also, if you need to compare the TPM version against multiple possibilities, then a switch statement makes for neater code:

```
$tmp = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\cimv2\security\microsofttpm -Class Win32_TPM 
Set-Location "C:\Users\ADministrator\Desktop\TPM Downgrade"

switch([Version]$tmp.ManufacturerVersion)
{
    {$_ -eq [Version]"7.62"} { '.\7.62 downgrade.cmd'}
    {$_ -eq [Version]"7.61"} { '.\7.61 downgrade.cmd'}
    {$_ -eq [Version]"7.60"} { '.\7.60 downgrade.cmd'}
    {$_ -eq [Version]"7.41"} { '.\7.41 downgrade.cmd'}
    {$_ -eq [Version]"7.40"} { '.\7.40 downgrade.cmd'}
    default {"Unable to find downgrade BIN for your firmware version"}
}
```

Comment: This solution works great. I originally believed I wouldn't have to specify ManufacturerVersion again in the conditional since it was singled out. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Note that there's absolutely no need to parse the version or compare it anyhow if you look at the structure of the code. The only relevant thing is whether the file corresponding to the version exists or not. This not only makes the code shorter it also avoids having to change the script if a new batch file is added.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$variable = get-WmiObject -Namespace root\cimv2\security\microsofttpm -Class Win32_Tpm | Select-Object ManufacturerVersion

if($variable.ManufacturerVersion -eq "8"){
Write-Host "success"
}else{
Write-Host "Fail"
}
```

Comment: This solution also works for the method. I believe defining ManufacturerVersion in the conditional is what allows it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your feedback and help. This is the final product and its working great.

```
$tmp = get-WmiObject -Namespace root\cimv2\security\microsofttpm -Class Win32_TPM 
Set-Location "C:\Users\ADministrator\Desktop\TPM Downgrade"

if ([Version]$tmp.ManufacturerVersion -eq [Version]"7.62"){
& '.\7.62 downgrade.cmd'
}elseif ([Version]$tmp.ManufacturerVersion -eq [Version]"7.61"){
& '.\7.61 downgrade.cmd'
}elseif ([Version]$tmp.ManufacturerVersion -eq [Version]"7.60"){
& '.\7.60 downgrade.cmd'
}elseif ([Version]$tmp.ManufacturerVersion -eq [Version]"7.41"){
& '.\7.41 downgrade.cmd'
}elseif ([Version]$tmp.ManufacturerVersion -eq [Version]"7.40"){
& '.\7.40 downgrade.cmd'
}else{
Write-Host "Unable to find downgrade BIN for your firmware version"
}
```

Comment: I updated my example with a slightly better explanation and a different method of implementing your final code that will improve its readability.  Any time you have multiple `if` statements, consider using a `switch` as the resulting code is often clearer.